# How do I manipulate multiple x-axes to correspond to each other, while on different scales?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a color magnitude diagram similar to:

[image: B-V Diagram]

I have three arrays that contain the exact same number of values.

`x1` = B-V (-.5 to 2)

`x2` = Temperature. (30,000 to 3000) and needs to be a log scale

`y1` = Magnitude (varies based on the others)

The `x1`, `x2`, and `y1` arrays are all linked, and I would like to plot them together in a scatterplot.

My code:

```
#PLOTS
x1 = bv_array       #B-V
x2 = t_array        #Temperature
y1 = Vavg_array     #Magnitude
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax1.xlim(-.5,2)
ax1.plot(x1, y1,'b--')
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.plot(x2, y1, 'go')
ax2.set_xlabel('Temperature')
ax2.invert_xaxis()

#ax2.xscale('log')
#plt.xscale('log')
#plt.scatter(x,y)

#plt.scatter(bv_array, Vavg_array, s = 1)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should just be able to pick a single point on the right hand edge of the graph where the axes should be aligned, and matplotlib will take it from there.

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.xlim(-.5,2) # Set it in axis 1 coords

ax1.plot(x1, y1,'b--')
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.plot(x2, y1, 'go')
ax2.set_xlabel('Temperature')
ax2.invert_xaxis()

ax2.xlim(-2, 3) # Set it in axis 2 coords
```

To determine the point, work out which axis (linear or log) will require more 'space' along the x axis, set its limit as its max, and then convert that to the coordinate space of the other axis to use it as its limit.